# Wix To many databases

Tags: database, wix, wix3.5

I am newbie in Wix. I use wix 3.5.. Just want to know, Can Wix connect to other database like MySQL, Oracle, DB2. or just to know the name of database and generata database script..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt WiX will ever have support for non Microsoft database engines.  InstallShield has native support for MSSQl, Oracle and MySQL but not for DB2.

You'll either have to come up with your own data driven custom action pattern to meet your needs or punt it to an activity done outside of the installer.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL extension that comes with WiX supports SQL Server. Other database servers aren't supported "in the box."

Comment: are you have any reference to other database, like mysql, and oracle.